# Function of a parameter and re-parametrisation

Tags: inference, nonparametric, parameterization

Consider a parametric model with likelihood
$f(\mathbf{y};\,\boldsymbol{\theta})$ where $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is
the parameter vector of length $p$ and $\mathbf{y}$ is the vector of
observations. Assume that $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ runs in an open domain
$\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}^p$.

For a smooth scalar-valued function $\psi_1(\boldsymbol{\theta})$
defined on $\Theta$, we can sometimes consider $\psi_1$ as
"candidate" parameter for the model. Indeed we can in certain cases
re-parameterise the model in such a way that $\psi_1$ becomes, say,
the first component for a smooth function
$\boldsymbol{\psi}(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ that transforms the domain
$\Theta$ into another domain $\Psi \subset \mathbb{R}^p$, in a smooth
and one-to-one fashion.  As a practical example, in a non-linear
regression framework $\psi_1$ can be the prediction at some chosen
"new" design point of interest. Inferring on $\psi_1$ is formally the
same thing as inferring on a parameter $\theta_i$.

What simple sufficient conditions on $\psi_1$ would ensure the existence
of the re-parameterised version? I guess that one of these could be
that $\partial \psi_1 / \partial \boldsymbol{\theta}$ does not vanish
on $\Theta$.

Comment: The vanishing of the gradient assures a *local* solution (by the Implicit Function Theorem) and therefore is a necessary condition.  It's not sufficient, though.  There is no general answer because it depends not only on $\psi_1$ but also on the topology of $\Theta.$ (Example: $\Theta=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\psi_1(x,y)=x^2+y^2.$)  If you have a *specific* problem, that perhaps could be answered.

Comment: Thank @whuber. My question is for quite general models: I am interested in
profile-likelihood inference on $\psi_1$. Maybe what I am quite confusely searching for is local, near the true parameter.